# What is Modern Analysis and Abstract Analysis?

Tags: analysis

Mostly I encounter textbooks named Analysis, Mathematical Analysis,... But recently, i encountered a book named A Course In Modern Analysis.

Please explain the difference between Modern Analysis and "Classical" Analysis. Also, please give some information about what Abstract Analysis means.

It's quite weird to me that the number of Modern Analysis textbooks is very small.

Comment: How about [this one](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540258308)?

Comment: @JohnMa WHAT?  The PoMos have invaded mathematics now?!  KHAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAN!

Comment: Nowadays instead of "modern algebra" (common in the early 20th century) we just say "algebra".  Similarly, we just say "analysis".  Historically, analysis modernized (became abstract) earlier than algebra did.  There is a tome *Plato's Ghost: The Modernist Transformation of Mathematics* by J. Gray explaining this.

Comment: There's usually not much difference, as these are mostly non-precise descriptive terms. Probably "classical analysis" would have an emphasis on calculation methods (inequalities, integral evaluations, asymptotic methods, etc.) and "modern analysis" would have an emphasis on soft analysis topics making use of metric and normed spaces. And of course, there are [some strong counterexamples](https://archive.org/details/courseofmodernan00whit) to this classification!

Comment: A little anecdote: When I was at the university, there department had rules that every other year there was to be a graduate level course in modern analysis and in the other years there had to be a graduate level course in classical analysis. When I took those courses, the professor asked to teach the course on modern analysis believed that everything that had happened after 1850 (or whenever, it's not really important) was modern enough, and the professor asked to teach the course on classical analysis believed everything that had happened before 1950 (again, I ...

Comment: ...don't remember and it's not important) was classical enough. So effectively what we studied in the course on classical analysis had been developed after what we studied in the course on modern analysis.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: Just wait until Dadaism hits math.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the age of the book.

"*A Course of Modern Analysis*" by E. Whittaker, first published in 1902, covers analytic functions, infinite series, Fourier series, Riemann integration etc. - all topics that today we would just call "analysis".

On the other hand "*Introduction to Modern Analysis*" by S. Kantorowitz, published in 2003, covers measure theory, functional analysis, Banach algebras, spectral theory etc. i.e. a more abstract and generalised treatment of analysis.